# SQL Server's Linked Servers - Java connection

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

In my Java application, I need to get metadata from Linked Servers of SQL Server. Type of Linked Server varies - can be SQL Server, Snowflake, Oracle, etc.

Is there a way of getting Linked Server's connection just like I would get for a direct connection to e.g. PostgreSQL? Viz code snippet.

```
// create java.sql.Connection
DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = connection.getMetaData();
databaseMetaData.getCatalog();
databaseMetaData.getSchemas();
...
```

Comment: I don't believe there's any way to do this using `DatabaseMetaData`.  However, you can always query the [`sys.servers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-servers-transact-sql) view.

Comment: Yes, that's true, thank you. Or as @d0little below suggests using stored procedures. I was hoping for some Java library/driver solution - Thing is I'd need also metadata of databases/catalogs/schemas/tables, so far it seems stored procedures (mainly ```sp_tables_ex```) are the way to go. Getting metadata using SQL would be imo pain due to the variety of Linked Servers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can using `DatabaseMetaData`, you can use

```sql
EXEC sp_linkedservers
```

to return meta data about linked servers